# Opening file error in Python : No such file or directory

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a newbie for writing here. So please please be bear with me.

I'm running this code to open my file and I put this in right directory 'data'. But my python sent me error message continuely.

I wrote this,

```
#file = unidecode.unidecode(open('./data/input.txt').read())
#file = unidecode.unidecode(open('./data/linux.txt').read())

file = unidecode.unidecode(open('./data/hh1.txt').read())
file_len = len(file)
print('file_len =', file_len)
```

and poped up this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-aa7f0f650918> in <module>()
  4 #file = unidecode.unidecode(open('./data/linux.txt').read())
  5 
  ----> 6 file = unidecode.unidecode(open('./data/hh1.txt').read())
  7 file_len = len(file)
  8 print('file_len =', file_len)

 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/hh1.txt
```

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX8dn.png)
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDF4E.png)

It's part of RNN(Recurrent Neural Network) code and it's part of processing text data to learn knitting pattern.

It's very simple error but I can't find a good way out.... So thank you for your patient to read this and I hope someone could help me out

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? ``FileNotFoundError`` means the file was not found. There is not much that can be done about it, other than ensuring the file is actually at the place specified. Is there actually a file at ``./data/hh1.txt`` or ``./hh1.txt``? Note that your code/error curiously enough includes both names, showing two different variants of the failing line..

Comment: The path is relative to your current working directory. Can you `import os;print(os.getcwd())` to find out what that is? Is this the directory you expect?

Comment: Oh.. I just noticed that I didn't edit all the code. Sorry for confusing. I put the right directory but I drag the wrong code that I edited particulary. I've edited again!!

Comment: I put that code and it showed me '/content'. So is it a behind path to be explained...?? I'm so new to here and stiff but thank you for your patient

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to open a file that is inside data folder in your relative path.

```
open('./data/hh1.txt').read()
```

If your script is in

```
/home/user/test.py
```

This one tries to open:

```
/home/user/data/hh1.txt
```

And if you use

```
open('./hh1.txt').read()
```

This one tries to open

```
/home/user/hh1.txt
```

That is in the same directory of your script.

You can use:

```
import os
print(os.listdir())
```

And it will show you all files in the current directory.

If you're using a relative path, check the path from your current directory to the destination file.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I've found three directory name so I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the path that you have entered is being interpreted differently than expected. This depends on a variety of this such as where the Python file you are executing is and whether it is part of a bigger project.

A good way to debug this is to expand the path you are trying to use into its absolute path. You can do this using the following code:

```py
import os
print(os.path.abspath("./data/hh1.txt"))
```

This will output something like `"/home/user/project/data/hh1.txt"`.

You can check the output of this and verify that your files are in the right location or if your path is possibly incorrect.

Comment: Oh wow... it shows me a '/content/data/hh1.txt' that I didn't acknowledged! Thank you so much for your information. XD But I put it on the open code but it's same.. I've put './content/data/hh1.txt' and just '/content/data/hh1.txt' both. Can you teach me what content mean?

Comment: @Dferrari, using this information, you should make sure that your file is in the `data/` directory which is inside the `content/` directory. The `content/` directory is simply the directory that is represented by `./` in your paths. Does this help?

Comment: Ah, I see. 'content/' is just same as './' I'm really sorry that I make you bother but can you please see my 'directory' photo just added on post? I've put that in right way I think....

Comment: @Dferrari, no worries. On Unix operating systems, `./` represents the current directory. It appears that the directory that you've placed your data into is not inside a `content/` directory. You should use `os.getcwd()` to find the directory that you should place your `data/` directory inside. Right now, you are executing a Python script that is in a different location than your data.

Comment: I've used your information and I finally succeed!!!!! I put that text file into data folder in my current file! I'm soooo appreciate your effor to make me understand. You're my hero... Thank you so much XD